# DAX query countdistinct

Tags: dax

I want to countdistinct from the following in DAX.

I have a table orders with the columns and sample as:

```
OrderNumber  Customer Vendor   OrderTaken   OrderDelivery   OrderBilling    Qty   Price
1              1        V1     2018/12/01    2019/01/10     2019/01/10       1      1
2              10       V1     2019/01/04    2019/01/07     2019/01/07       1      1
3              100      V2     2019/01/02    2019/01/04     2019/01/06       1      1
4              100      V2     2019/01/02    2019/07/01     2019/07/01       1      1
(              10       V1     2020/01/04    2020/01/07     2020/01/07       1      1
```

Date Format is yyyy/MM/dd

I want to count the price and count the number of distinct customer for each vendor from the 1st January to the 10th January billed and the ordertaken before the 10th Januray that are not billed.

I am able to calculate the sum for the price, one for billed order and one for ordertaken but I need to count the number of distinct client even if there is an order billed and one not yet billed.

For the sum I have done:

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'orders'[vendor],
    "Billed", CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Orders'[Price] ),
        'orders'[OrderBilling] >= VALUE ( "01/01/2019" ),
        'orders'[OrderBilling] <= VALUE ( "10/01/2019" )
    ),
    "NotBilled", CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'ZBW00001'[CANET(-DATION)] ),
        'orders'[OrderBilling] > VALUE ( "20190110" ),
        'orders'[OrderTaken]   <= VALUE ( "20190110" )
    )
)
```

I got as result

Vendor     Billed        NotBilled
V1            2
V2            1              1

The desired output is to have the number of distinct customer from the two periods:

```
   'orders'[OrderBilling] >= VALUE ( "01/01/2019" ),
   'orders'[OrderBilling] <= VALUE ( "10/01/2019" )
and
    'orders'[OrderBilling] > VALUE ( "20190110" ),
    'orders'[OrderTaken]   <= VALUE ( "20190110" )
```

If I used the same method as the SUM, i will have

```
Vendor     NbcustomerBilled        NbCustomerNotBilled
V1            2
V2            1                           1
```

and the number of distinct user will be 4 that is not the truth, should be 3.

Desired output

```
Vendor  NbCustomerDistinct SumSales
  V1              2              2           ( Two customers 1 and 10)
  V2              1              2           ( Only one customer 100 )
```

I do not see how can I get it. If somebody can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The number of distinct vendors is 2, which is the column you're summarizing. If you want customers, summarize over 'orders'[Customer] instead.
Also you can use the DATE-function instead of VALUE. Makes the code easier to read; DATE(2019;01;10)
In addition, in the NotBilled calculation you seem to have the same date in the two filters.

Comment: Sorry I have made an error on NotBilled formula (I have changed). The count is on Vendor column

Comment: If you post the desired output it will be easier to help you. At the moment I don't understand what the question/problem is.

Comment: I have added the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure how you want to calculate SumSales, but I guess you can figure out how to add that column by extending this code:

```
NewTable = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'orders';
    [vendor];
    "NbCustomerDistinct"; DISTINCTCOUNT('orders'[Customer])
    /*"SumSales = Add calculation to get SumSales here*/
)
```

Comment: Thank you for you help; but you do not take in account the filters who make the trick more complex

Comment: That's because you did not specify how SumSales was supposed to be calculated. In the original code you hade "Billed" and "NotBilled" in the desired output you had "NbCustomerDistinct" and "SumSales" and you only specified how NbCustomerDistinct was supposed to be calculated.

Comment: I have added how to calculate in te original post. I hope that is more clear

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do it not sure that is the best,

```
EVALUATE 
VAR InternalTable = 
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( 
        'orders'[vendor],
        "Total",CALCULATE(SUM('Orders'[Price]),
               'orders'[OrderBilling] >= VALUE ( "01/01/2019" ),
               'orders'[OrderBilling] <= VALUE ( "10/01/2019" ))
            +CALCULATE(SUM('Orders'[Price]]),
               'orders'[OrderBilling] > VALUE ( "10/01/2019" ),
                'orders'[OrderTaken]   <= VALUE ("10/01/2019" ))
            )

Return
GROUPBY(
    InternalTable,
    'orders'[vendor],
    "Total_Sales",SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(),[Total]),
    "Current_Clients",COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(),[Total])
)
```